# Workflow 4 and multiple responses

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0, workflow-foundation-4

I have a workflow which has a custom activity which calls a web service. This workflow is called by a silverlight application.

The problem I have is that when I call the workflow the first time I get one response. If I call it again, I get two responses etc (I am using a Receive and SendReply activity).

I thought this was happening because every time I call the workflow a new instance was created and every instance of the workflow running would reply. I have tried using correlation to see if this would resolve the problem but this does not in this case.

Does anyone know why this would be the case.

Regards

Mike

Comment: Do you mean you are sending one SOAP request and that gets two SOAP response messages? Sounds very unlikely. Did you trace this with Fiddler?

Comment: I am definitely not getting two Soap responses back. I am receiving more than one response from the workflow. thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have some logic error in your workflow where it returns a result, loops back to return a new result on the second request but the second result is added to the fist result instead of clearing it first. Can happen quite easily if you are returning a collection of items or something similar. Remember that the workflow instance is stateful and any variables will be preserved from one SOAP request to the next.

Comment: Are you saying that the variables I have defined are shared between all instances of running workflows?

Comment: No, not shared between workflow instances. But they keep their value as long as a specific workflow instance is alive.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.

Turns out that the problem was with my silverlight client and the event handler calling the workflow. As soon as I unregister the event after the call has completed. Everything works as expected.

Thanks

Mike

Comment: Sharing a proxy object between calls in an async world is never a good plan.